# 1:1 relationship using Fluent API in a separate file - MVC5, ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I’m doing MVC5 application using ASP.NET Identity. I want to create 1:1 relationship using Fluent API in a separate file. The relationship should be between tables User and UserInfo.

UserInfo class:

```
public class UserInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

In IdentityModels.cs I added this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
  //… 
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserInfoConfigurations());

// If I define relationship like this here, it’s working, 
// but I want it in a separate file.
// modelBuilder.Entity<UserInfo>()
//       .HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(p => p.User);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

UserInfoConfigurations.cs where I want to define 1:1 relationship:

```
public class UserInfoConfigurations : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserInfo>
{
    public UserInfoConfigurations()
    {
        ToTable("UserInfo");            
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnType("NVarchar").HasMaxLength(30);
        Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnType("NVarchar").HasMaxLength(30);
        // and so on for each property

// I want it here. I thought it’s something like this, but it’s not working.
     .HasRequired(t => t.User);
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are your reasons to want the definition in "separate file"? what's wrong with default API and define relations in `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: Because I have a lot more other configurations that need to be applied for each property (I edited the post), so if I keep all of them in IdentityModels.cs (especially when I have more tables with their own configurations) it would be a mess. That’s why I prefer to keep it separately and then just call it in ApplicationDbContext.
And if I define a relationship in ApplicationDbContext for UserInfo entity then I can’t call that separate file anymore to apply that other configurations.

Comment: I mean, if I don’t find out other way, then I’ll just put all configurations for that table in ApplicationDbContext, but I really thought there’s a way to define that relation like I want it.

Comment: Why do you say "it doesn't work" on the UserInfoConfigurations class? "HasRequired(t => t.User);" should at least compile.

Comment: It does compile, but when I try to create a new user, then the code breaks, because the relation is not working and it won't create an instance of UserInfo entity.